# How to simplify the answer of $ \frac{d y}{d x}=\frac{1}{1-x^{2}} \cdot y+(1+x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, absolute-value

I need to compute the answer of
$ \frac{d y}{d x}=\frac{1}{1-x^{2}} \cdot y+(1+x)$

I have tried Integrating factor method and I get

$y=e^{\int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{1-x^{2}}  d{x}}\left(1+\int_{0}^{x}(1+x) e^{-\int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{1-x^{2}} d x} d x\right)$
$=\sqrt{\left|\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right|}\left(1+\int_{0}^{x}(x+1) \sqrt{\mid\frac{1-x}{1+x}\mid}  d x\right)$

But I can’t remove the absolute value. So anyone can help me?

Comment: If you ignore the modulus, the answer comes out to be $$y(x) = (c_1 \sqrt(x + 1))/\sqrt(1 - x) + (\sqrt(x + 1)\sqrt(1 - x^2) x)/(2 \sqrt(1 - x)) + (\sqrt(x + 1) \sin^{-1}(x))/(2 \sqrt(1 - x))$$

Comment: As we get a term of inverse of sine x, so it is already incorporated in the answer that x<1

Comment: But when x>1, I think your formula is invaild.